# User Permissions on a Calendar

Tags: permissions

I have read access to a sharepoint calendar and can view the page with no issues.  I do not have access to the site though which is by design.  I am using the code below to check if I have permission to the site.  Some calendars work while others don't even though I can see events on the various calendars.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(url)
{
  clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
  string userLoginName = "i:0#.f|membership|" + owner.ToLower();
  List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
  clientContext.Load(oList);
  var effectPermissions = oList.GetUserEffectivePermissions(userLoginName);
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
  if (effectPermissions.Value.Has(PermissionKind.ViewListItems))
  {
      return CallStatus.OK;
  }
}
```

Is the GetUserEffectivePermissions check only a certain level of permission?  Cant figure out why some calendars get the OK while others don't.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try
{
    ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
    string userLogin = "i:0#.f|membership|" + owner.ToLower();
    List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
    clientContext.Load(oList);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    User usr = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(userLogin);
    clientContext.Load(usr);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    ClientResult<BasePermissions> result = item.GetUserEffectivePermissions(usr.LoginName);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    if(result.Value.Has(PermissionKind.ViewListItems))
    {
        return CallStatus.Ok;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //User has no permission
}
```

OK will get returned if the user has `ViewListItems` permission.

Check the `PermissionKind` enumeration

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.permissionkind(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: As my code above illustrates, I am using: effectPermissions.Value.Has(PermissionKind.ViewListItems)
But I am using getting the catch (WebException ex)
            {
                return CallStatus.UnAuthorized;
            }

Comment: @pomo i have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you.  I used the code you provided and I get the same results.  Some calendars I can get an OK while others I get an Access Denied.  So my issue must be my logic.  What level permissions does a user need to get an OK?  I am able to view the calendar pages no problem.  If I have a url: https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/stuff/stuffer/Lists/Calendar/calendar.aspx  Would my siteurl be https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/stuff/stuffer